# Admin-area broken through weird issues

Tags: php, functions, apache

Sorry for my bad English - it is not my mother language.

Just installed wordpress 3.9. The admin area looks a bit broken all though I have fixed some things with switching the magic quotes to off

But the admin area that allows customizing looks a bit funny. See the [refering image](http://www.literaturen.org/tmp/customizing_1.jpg)

**update:** besides the parts that can be seen on the image - i can see nothing - the whole screen is emtpy - and i cannot click anything. Nothing happens

Btw; if you want to ave a look a the backend I would be happy. Just send me a mail - to get the consent (and passwd ) to the admin-area.

Comment: Please improve this question. "Here is a picture what's wrong and how do I fix is?" is not an acceptable question. Post the relevant code and provide a detailed description of the problem.

Comment: For security reasons, never give your login details to anyone. Bad idea! According the included image, you are using the twentyfourteen theme. My bet is that your problem is caused by a plugin that is not yet compatible with wordpress 3.9 or have a bug. Delete your plugins one by one and test after each one if your problem is cleared.

Comment: hello dear s ha dum hello dear peter: 
**update:** besides the parts that can be seen on the image - i can see nothing - the whole screen is emtpy - and i cannot click anything. Nothing happens

Comment: dear pieter - the idea with the plugin looks / sounds good. i will check all your ideas. thx alot

Comment: @zero well, this is the only solution to your problem. there should be a plugin that is breaking your jquery, some kind of conflict. I cannot be wordpress nor the twentyfourteen theme

Comment: @zero, another thing to note when you are commenting and you need to address your comment to someone specific, just type `@`, and a list of users will appear, just click on the user's name you are directing your comment at

Comment: Try reuploading all the WordPress files, sometimes this can happen if there was a glitch in the original upload.